# How to find False discovery rate of a ML model? Situation explained below

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, statistics

Lets say:- ML Model denied 1000 transactions
FDR= FP/(FP+TP)

I randomly picked 400 accounts and checked if the model denied good user or bad user.

Good user denied- 110

Bad user denied - 290

How will I calculate False Discover rate of the model. Can it be based on the sample that I checked manually and then extrapolate ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can estimate the FDR by
$$110 / 400 = 27.5\%$$

the approach of sampling some data and estimating the empirical FDR in there is valid, it's the same as estimating the mean of a population using a sample, it makes sense, and the more data you use the more confident you're going to be on your estimate, as long as you're sampling randomly.

400 seems a pretty decent number to estimate FDR, so your estimate is going to be pretty good.